# Configuring local laptop to a domain IP

Tags: networking, dns, subdomain

I want to configure my laptop with Ubuntu or Windows to connect to my website.

I want to run a web server directly from my laptop, which can be accessed from my website i.e. www.xyz.com/laptop_projects

I have a static IP, a .com address and a laptop running Ubuntu and windows with me.

Can anyone, let me know, how to configure so that anyone accessing my website can directly access projects running on my laptop.

Hope I am clear, let me know, if anything is unclear.

I have a macbook pro, if someone has a solution for mac only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What probably you are looking for is for a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) you could use [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) for this, for example, if you would like to show the contents of your laptop within this URL `www.example.com/projects` on your server hosting `www.example.com` you could have something like this:

```
location /projects {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://your-laptop:8000;
}
```

Now you may want to use a dynamic DNS for your laptop so that you don't have to frequently modify your Nginx configuration.

For testing purposes and just serving static files, you could is this tiny web server: https://go-www.com/

More nginx examples: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Okay.. Let me try this. :)